# how solve this appears illegal character when i click two times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function works well when i click the first time but when i click the second time receive a error  in this part

```
eval("var " + data + "=sinvnword;");
```

Code:

```
$('a.play-video').click(function(){
  var currentLocation = window.location;


  var fullurl = window.location.href; 
  url =  fullurl.split("sendx")[1];

  var sinvnword = $('.question-label.active').last().text();

  console.log(sinvnword);
  var data =url ;
  eval("var " + data + "=sinvnword;");

  console.log(AXY + "GETIT");
  console.log(AXY+"mor");

  console.log(AXY + "muerte"); 
});
```

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, don't use `eval`. You have a pretty nasty XSS vulnerability there.

Comment: what another options i could use ?

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to do, but this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Comment: i see my error in the url appears a "#" because i click one time

Comment: Still, *don't use eval*. The way you are using it compromises your site's security.

Comment: ok i dont use this in the future; very thank you

Comment: What error do you get? Is it declaring the same thing twice with `var`?

Comment: the error was a # of the url that appears after the first click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `eval` to create dynamic *variable* names, simply use dynamic *property names*:

```
var data = {};

$('a.play-video').click(function(){
  var currentLocation = window.location;

  var fullurl = window.location.href; 
  var key = fullurl.split("sendx")[1];

  var sinvnword = $('.question-label.active').last().text();

  console.log(sinvnword);
  data[key] = sinvnword;

  console.log(AXY + "GETIT");
  console.log(AXY+"mor");

  console.log(AXY + "muerte"); 
});
```